# Office.js - get the email body content using getAsync and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get the body content of emails in Outlook using the `body.getAsync()` method:

```js
let body = '';
body = Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
   "text",
    function (result) {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            body = result.value;
        }
    }
);
console.log(body);
```

In this case, `console.log(body)` returns undefined. However, if I try to log the result inside the `getAsync` callback:

```js
if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      body = result.value;
      console.log(body);

}
```

It works fine, and the email body content is successfully returned.

Comment: Try to change the declaration of `body` variable from `let` to `var` and check the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Javascript runs synchronously from top to bottom unless you use callbacks, promises or async/await. Essentially, `body` is undefined because `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` has not completed when the `console.log()` is called. When `getAsync()` completes, then the callback function is called. Also, `getAsync()` returns void not the message body. You need to use the callback to access the body.

What you could do is:

```js
let body = '';
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  "text",
  function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      body = result.value;
      doSomething(body)
    }
  }
)

function doSomething(body){
  console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: This is basically a good answer, but (pet peeve) it isn't the case that "JavaScript run asynchronously from top to bottom". JavaScript is a synchronous, single-threaded language. Modern JavaScript engines (such as in modern browsers or Node.js) get around this by using the asynchronous capacity of the parent operating system. This enables the use of asynchronous methods in JavaScript. JS will start an async method and immediately move on to the next line without waiting for it to complete (unless it is awaited in some way). But it does wait for synchronous methods.

Comment: @RickKirkham oops typo on my part. I did mean synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Use object to retain its value.

```
    let bodyObject = {};
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
  "text",
  function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
      bodyObject.body = result.value;
      
    }
  }
)
console.log(bodyObject.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In Script Lab, juicy-g's Answer Worked For Me - Goutam Kumar's Worked On Second Run

For testing purposes, I found that Goutam's answer was easier.

See my code at bottom for my Script Lab Add-In Snippet test.

However, it would NOT log the body to the console on the first run from the Script Lab Add-In, but it would log the body to the console on the second button push of my Run button.

When I used juicy-g's version, it would return the body on the FIRST button push.

##### My Code Snippet For Script Lab Using ROUGHLY Goutam's Approach

```
$("#run").on("click", run);

let bodyObject = {body: ""};

function run() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    "text",
    function (result) {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        bodyObject.body = result.value;
      }
    }
  );

  console.log(bodyObject.body);
}
```

##### My Code Snippet For Script Lab Using ROUGHLY juicy-g's Approach

```
$("#run").on("click", run);

function run() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    "text",
    function (bodyResult) {
      // await sleep(1000);
      if (bodyResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        showBody(bodyResult.value);
      }
    });
}

function showBody(body) {
  console.log(body);
}
```

This cost me some time to learn, so I hope this helps save time for others.